# Error 0: The address xxxxx is not in the database

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation

After installing my website on a local machine using Bitnami, I can see that both files and database have been properly restored.
However, the home page is diplaying the error:

```
The address xxx is not in the database.
```

I've searched the issue and probably it is related with GeoIP, but can't figure out how to solve it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using a security extension by which only certain IP's addresses are allowed to access your site?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: I've done a mass find on the following string: `is not in the database.` in all Joomla language files and it doesn't exist. Therefore this message is coming from a 3rd party extension, most likely a plugin. Try disabling your 3rd party plugins one by one and see which was is causing the issue.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help. I found out it was a Regular Labs Plugin that uses Geo IP, it was a nightmare to figure that out.

Comment: Hey can you help with my website config of yootheme pro template?

Comment: Please ask a new question giving specific details as to what the issue is, and the communoty will try to help :)